# Remover observations for which there is not a duplicate

Tags: r, dataset, duplicates

I would like to break a dataset into two frames - one for which the original dataset has duplicate observations based on a condition and one for which the original dataset does not have duplicate observations based on a condition. In the following example, I would like to break the frame into one for which there is only one coder for an observation and one for which there are two coders::

```
frame <- data.frame(id = c(1,1,1,2,2,3), coder = c("A", "A", "B", "A", "B", "A"), y = c(4,5,4,1,1,2))
frame
```

For this, I would like to produce, such that:

```
  frame1:

     id coder y
  1  1     A 4
  2  1     A 5
  3  1     B 4
  4  2     A 1
  5  2     B 1

  frame2:

  6  3     A 2
```

Comment: Hi, i'm not sure exactly what you're asking. You'd like to split a data.frames, one with duplicates and one without? what are you considering de-duplicating by: the entire row, a specific column, or a combination of columns?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `aggregate` to determine the ids you want in each data frame:

```
cts <- aggregate(coder~id, frame, function(x) length(unique(x)))
cts
#   id coder
# 1  1     2
# 2  2     2
# 3  3     1
```

Then you can subset as appropriate based on this:

```
subset(frame, id %in% cts$id[cts$coder >= 2])
#   id coder y
# 1  1     A 4
# 2  1     A 5
# 3  1     B 4
# 4  2     A 1
# 5  2     B 1
subset(frame, id %in% cts$id[cts$coder < 2])
#   id coder y
# 6  3     A 2
```

Answer (score 0):

You may also try:

```
 indx <- !colSums(!table(frame$coder, frame$id))
 frame[frame$id %in% names(indx)[indx],]
#   id coder y
#1  1     A 4
#2  1     A 5
#3  1     B 4
#4  2     A 1
#5  2     B 1

 frame[frame$id %in% names(indx)[!indx],]
#  id coder y
#6  3     A 2
```

#### Explanation

```
 table(frame$coder, frame$id) 
  #    1 2 3
  #  A 2 1 1
  #  B 1 1 0 #Here for id 3, B==0
```

- If we Negate that, the result would be a logical index
- `!table(frame$coder, frame$id)`.
- Do the `colSums` of the above, which results

  ```
  # 1 2 3 
  # 0 0 1
  ```
- Negate again and get the index for `ids` and subset those ids which are `TRUE`
- From this you can subset by matching with the names of the ids